# Professor gets wet

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, solution-verification, markov-chains, ergodic-theory

**Problem :** A professor has $N$ umbrellas . He walks to the office in the morning and walks home in the evening . If it's raining he likes to carry an umbrella and if it's fine he doesn't . Suppose that it rains on each journey with probability $p$ , independently of past weather . What's the long-run proportion of journeys on which the professor gets wet ?

**Question :** I want to see if my plan below is viable . Or you can share your approach .

(The problem's cited directly from exercise 1.10.2 of Markov Chains by James R. Norris .)

---

**My interpretation :** Suppose now professor leaves his home . If he sees it's raining ,  he will pick up an umbrella , if any , and he'll not get wet , otherwise he will . The umbrella will follow him to office , which he may not bring back .  If he sees it's not raining , he'll just walk out , and he'll not get wet because **I assumed it'll not rain in the middle of his journey** .  By journey I mean each commute between home & office , so 2 journeys every day . "The long-run proportion of journeys ..." means $\frac{\text{ no.journeys he gets wet}}{ \text{total no. of journeys } }$ when total no. of journeys tends to infinity .

---

**My plan :**

Assume $(1-p)p \neq 0 , N<\infty$ .

Let $(X_n)_{n\ge 0}$ be the number of umbrellas at his home at night , suppose $X_0 = N$ . The state space is $ \{ 0,...,N \}$ and transition probabilities
$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{cc}
p_{i,i+1} = p_{i,i-1} = (1-p)p , & p_{ii} = 1 - 2(1-p)p , \; i= 1,..,N-1 \\
p_{01} =  p , &p_{00} = 1 - p   \\
p_{N,N-1} =  (1-p)p , & p_{NN} = 1 - (1-p)p  
\end{array}\right.
$$ .
This time homogeneous markov chain is irreducible and recurrent .

Let
$$
Y_n =
\left\{
\begin{array}{cc}
1 & \text{ if } \{\text{Professor gets wet tomorrow}\}\\
0 & \text{otherwise} 
\end{array}\right.
$$
where
$$
\{\text{Professor gets wet tomorrow}\} = 
(\{ X_n = 0 \} \cap \{ \text{ rains tomorrow morning } \} )\\ \cup 
 (\{ X_n = N \} \cap \{ \text{ doesn't rain tomorrow morning } \} \cap   \{ \text{ rains tomorrow evening } \} )
$$

Note that he will only get wet on at most 1 journey each day .  Let $Z_n=(X_n,Y_n)$ , the state space is
$$
 \{(0,1)  , (N,1)\} \cup  \{(0,0) , ... , (N,0) \} 
$$

The transition probabilities (please scroll)
$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{cccc}
p_{(i,0)(i+1,0)} = p_{(i,0)(i-1,0)} = (1-p)p , & p_{(i,0)(i,0)} = 1 - 2(1-p)p , \; i= 2,..,N-2 \\
p_{(1,0)(0,0)} =  (1-p)^2p , & p_{(1,0)(0,1)} =  (1-p)p^2  , 
& p_{(1,0)(2,0)} = (1-p)p ,  &  p_{(1,0)(1,0)} =  1 - 2(1-p)p    \\
p_{(N-1,0)(N,0)} =  (1-p)p(p+(1-p)^2) , & p_{(N-1,0)(N,1)} =  ((1-p)p)^2 , & 
p_{(N-1,0)(N-2,0)} = (1-p)p , & p_{(N-1,0)(N-1,0)} =  1 - 2(1-p)p \\
p_{(0,0)(0,1)} = (1-p)p , & p_{(0,0)(1,0)} = p  , &  p_{(0,0)(0,0)} = 1 - (1-p)p - p \\
p_{(N,0)(N,1)} = \left(1 - \frac{(1-p)p}{p+(1-p)^2}\right)(1-p)p , & p_{(N,0)(N-1,0)} = \frac{(1-p)p}{p+(1-p)^2} , &  p_{(N,0)(N,0)} = 1 - \left(1 - \frac{(1-p)p}{p+(1-p)^2}\right)(1-p)p  -  \frac{(1-p)p}{p+(1-p)^2} \\
p_{(0,1)(0,0)} = (1-p)^2 , & p_{(0,1)(1,0)} = p , & p_{(0,1)(0,1)}  = 1 - (1-p)^2 - p \\
p_{(N,1)(N,0)} = p+(1-p)^2 , & p_{(N,1)(N-1,0)} = 0 , & p_{(N,1)(N,1)} = 1 - p-(1-p)^2
\end{array}\right.
$$
$(Z_n)_{n\ge 0}$ is also a time homogeneous irreducible recurrent Markov chain . Informally , this Markov chain looks like 2 triangles connected to each end of a bar .

My plan is to find the the expected return times $m_{(0,1)} , m_{(N,1)} $ to states $(0,1) , (N,1) $ resp. by solving linear equations using recurrence relation and minimization  , and the desired quantity will be
$\frac{1}{m_{(0,1)}} + \frac{1}{m_{(N,1)}}  $ by Theorem 1.10.2  .

---

Theorem 1.10.2  Let $P$ be irreducible and let $\lambda$ be any distribution . If $(X_n)_{n\ge 0}$ is Markov$(\lambda,P)$ then
$$
\mathbb{P}\left( \frac{V_i(n)}{n} \to \frac{1}{m_i} \text{ as } n \to \infty  \right) = 1 
$$
where $V_i(n) = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} 1_{\{X_k = i\}}$ and $m_i$ is expected return time to state $i$ .

(From Markov Chains by James R. Norris)

Comment: I suppose we don't have to consider cases where it starts raining while the professor is walking?

Comment: @paw88789 yes , I agree .

Answer (score 1):

I solved it for 4 umbrellas,

Assume you are at home and going to office. There can be 5 states either you have 01234 Umbrellas at home. There are four events possible : (rain rain) ; (Rain, no rain) ; (no rain, rain) ; (no rain,no rain).

you can construct a probability transition matrix in the case of each of these events starting from every state. Then you can calculate the steady state probabilities of All the five states.Then,

P(wet) = s0 * P(rain),

Since the case going from office to home is symmetrical and the probability of being at office or being at home initially is equal the final answer is the above expression only.

upon calculation I found that (s1 = s2 = s3 = s4 = 1/(q + 4)) and s0 = (q/(q + 4)) . Where q = 1- p.

I think due to the symmetricicty of transition matrix it can be extended to case of N umbrellas  , (s1 = ... sN =  (1/q + n)) and s0 = q/(q + n).